# How to retreive user information using api call and passing values in it

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api

How to retrieve different users email , company name address using api call and passing firstname and lastname?

Comment: Using which API? What have you tried so far?

Comment: using metadataapi , restapi or any sales force api

Comment: I think you must pass something that is unique to a record. firstname and lastname may not be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the [Query](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_query.htm) resource of the [Force.com REST API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/). Your SOQL query would be something like `SELECT Email, Account.Name, Account.BillingAddress FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Doe'`. As another user mentioned, you should be prepared to handle multiple results.